# Need replacement of &#160;

Tags: xslt

I'm in a need of replacing `&#160;` with an empty space. in browser IE 9 it's working fine. but in IE 11, its displayed as invalid character (a small box sort of thing).

Comment: What is your question? You've tagged this XSLT but you've not shown any XSLT code not any indication of what the XML you're processing looks like or what output you need to produce.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm in a need of replacing `&#160;` with an empty space.

Use the `translate()` function. No code, because no code given.